# App wont run unless you update google play services

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services

Whenever I run my app in my emulator, which uses the Google maps API, I get the error "App wont run unless you update google play services". I've digged through some other questions about the same topic here on SO, since there are many, but I did not find a solution yet. So how do I get the Google maps API to work on my emulator?

When I go through installed apps on the emlator I don't see Google Play services in the list. So I am guessing this is the problem? If so, how do I get this on my device? Or isn't it possible at all on an emulator to use Google Play services?

I am using an emulator with Google API enabled.

Here is my Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thomas.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'` in your dependencies, which _is_ `Google Play Serivces`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question, since I realized it wasn't clear enough. What I meant was that I get this error on my emulator device and how to fix it in order to run my application.

Comment: I was afraid of this. The big problem is that I have a device which runs lollipop, but I want to also be able to test it on older versions of Android. :(

Comment: What kind of emulator did you create - one with Google APIs?

Comment: Yep, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So There was no way to make Google play services run the default Android emulator shipped with the SDK . So instead I started to look into other emulators and found xamarin android player. I got Google play store and Google play services working on it in no time. So if anyone also has this issue, use this emulator instead. The only downside is you can't debug in it.

Comment: How do you use xamarin android player with Android Studio?

Comment: I don't. I just drag and drop the .apk into the player and it installs it. As I said I can't debug it, which is kinda unfortunate. But according to: http://www.markawilkinson.info/2015/09/using-xamarin-android-player-with.html, it is definately possible, it does't work yet for me, but I need to upgrade my player.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I opened my emulator, went to Settings -> Apps -> Google Play services, and noted the version (in my case, 8.1.65). Then I opened my `build.gradle` and saw that the version there for `com.google.android.gms:play-services` was 8.3.0. I changed it to 8.1.0 and it worked on the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to do a check in your code if the user has Google play services installed. If they dont, prompt them to download it from the play store.

Comment: I get this error on my emulator. I currently cannot test this part since I can't get Google play services on my emulator and run my application properly because of this error. Sorry if I was unclear, I've edited my question. The question is how t get Google play services to work on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this limitation of Android emulators by using Samsung's Device Test Lab - http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab.  You can launch from a multitude of devices there, which all have Play Services.